# Why jQuery do not remove attribute name for class or style when there is no attribute value?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why jQuery do not remove attribute name for class or style when there is no attribute value?

For example, `$('<div>').addClass('foo').removeClass('foo')` returns `[<div class>​</div>​]` and not `[<div>​</div>​]`

My guess is performance, but maybe there are other reasons.

Here is jQuery implementation:

https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/attributes.js#L88

Comment: I think that's more of a browser artefact :)

Comment: Might be because you removed the class.. and not the attribute class?

Comment: @Jack in this instance, it's a jQuery artefact, not a browser one.

Comment: @Alnitak it's browser too, if you use `Element.prototype.classList`. My question is why jQuery prefer string parsing even in case browser don't support `classList`

Comment: @Mohsen it looks like they just never got around to implementing it - see http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/5087

Comment: @Mohsen A likely reason is compatibility. A major part of what jQuery does is ensure consistency between browsers. If you look through the source code you'll find fixes for batshit browser quirks you've probably never heard about. Using native implementations of anything risks harming consistency of behaviour across browsers, requires even hacks to normalize it, writing tests against someone else's code, and having to provide your own implementation for browsers that don't have that feature yet. **tl;dr:** when it comes to browsers, "native" does not necessarily mean "better".

Comment: @Alnitak that's right! They don't even use classList https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/attributes.js#L88

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compare (from Chrome 23):

```
> $('<div>').addClass('foo').removeClass('foo').attr('class')
""
```

and:

```
> $('<div>').attr('class')
undefined
```

In the former case, the element still has a `class` attribute, but it has no value.

In the latter case, element has no `class` attribute at all.

What's happening is that jQuery uses simple string manipulations to remove classes, and if the resulting string is empty then that's what's used - it never removes the `class` attribute entirely.

In Chrome, even the DOM3 `classList` functions leave behind an empty `class` attribute - calling `el.classList.add('foo')` followed by `el.classList.remove('foo')` will (in the absence of any other classes) leave you with an empty `class`.